# How find the greatest odd number $N$, such for any odd $k(<N)$ if $(N,k)=1$,then $k$ is prime number.

Tags: number-theory

> Find the greatest odd numbers $N$,such for any odd $k(<N)$ if $\gcd (N,k)=1$,then $k$ is prime number.

It is said the odd  $N\le 105$?

if $N=5$,then $k=3$ such $\gcd(k,N)=1$,and $k=3$ is prime number.

if $N=7$,then $k=3,5$ such it.

but How can prove the greatest odd numbers $N?$.

Comment: Any number of the form $18k+1$ is coprime with $9$, hence the greatest $N$ you are looking for is less than $19$.

Comment: No, check 105 @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,Hello, the coprime is mean? and then How find the greast odd?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but if we take $N=19$, then $9$ is odd and coprime with $19$, since $\gcd(9,19)=1$, but $9$ is not a prime.

Comment: $105$ is a number greater than $19$ which satisfies the conditions. I think I have a solution, but I use Bertrand's postulate. Would the OP allow it? Where is this problem from?And @JackD'Aurizio your example shows $19$ doesn't work. But does it help?

Comment: @shadow10,is from student ask it.maybe it Mathematical olympiad problems,and can you post you Bertrand's postulate methods? Thank you

Comment: OK then, I am giving the solution.There might be elementary methods, but don't judge me :P

Comment: I'm looking forward to your answer,Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_k$ be the $k$'th prime, and the  smallest odd prime not dividing $a$. Then $a$ satisfies that property if and only if $a<p_k^2$.

if $k$ is the number of the smallest prime not dividing $a$ then $a$ must be divisible by all the primes smaller than $p$. So $a\geq p_2\cdot p_3\dots p_{k-1}$.

If $p_k=11$ we get $a<121$ and $105$ works since it is divisible by $3\cdot5\cdot7$.

However for $p_k>11$ we get $ p_2\cdot p_3\dots p_{k-1}>p_k^2$. So building the desired prime is impossible.

---

The proof of the last claim comes from bertrands postulate, which tells you there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$ in particular this tells us $p_{k+1}\geq 2p_k\implies p_{k+1}^2\geq 4p_k^2$.

So $p_k$ grows a lot slower than $p_2\cdot p_3\dots p_{k-1}$. So all you have to do is prove it doesn't work for $p_k=13$ and then use induction.

Comment: hehe this was the proof, I was trying to get at. But my typing speed failed me. :D +1

Comment: Hello,this is why? Let $p_{k}$ be the k'th primes, and the smallest odd prime not dividing a. Then a satisfies that property if and only if $a<p^2_{k}$.

Comment: because if we had $a>(p_k)^2$ then that number would be comprime to $a$, smaller than $a$ and not a prime, which is exactly what you don't want. Moreover if that number is larger than $a$ then so are all of the other odd numbers coprime to $a$ and which are not perfect squares.

Comment: Thank you,and can you post this inequality to prove it? $p_{2}\cdots p_{k-1}>p^2_{k}$?

Comment: base case: $3*5*7*11>13^2$. We now use induction, where the inductive hypothesis is $3*5*7*11* \dots p_k>p_{k+1}^2$. Clearly $p_k+1>4$ so $3*5*7*11\dots *p_k*p_{k+1}>43*5*7*11* \dots p_k>4(p_{k+1}^2)\geq 4p_k$.The last inequality comes fro bertrand's postulate.

Comment: so your answer is $115?$

Comment: I made a typo, it should be 105=3*5*7

Comment: Yeah, that's where Bertrand comes in